# java: Open folder on button click

Tags: java, windows, api, directory

In java, how can we open a **separate** folder (e.g. c:) for user on click of a button, e.g like the way " locate this file on disk" or  "open containing folder" does when we download a file and we want to know where it was saved.  The goal is to save user's time to open a browser and locate the file on disk. 
Thanks ( image below is an example from what firefox does) 
[image]

I got the answer:
Here is what worked for me in Windows 7:

```
        File foler = new File("C:\\"); // path to the directory to be opened
        Desktop desktop = null;
        if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
        desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
        }

        try {
        desktop.open(foler);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
```

Thanks to @AlexS

Comment: Your edited code can throw a NullPointerException, unless you open it inside the block guarded by the `if` statement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume you have a file. With java.awt.Desktop you can use something like this:

```
public static void openContaiingFolder(File file) {
    String absoluteFilePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
    File folder = new File(absoluteFilePath.substring(0, absoluteFilePath.lastIndexOf(File.separator)));
    openFolder(folder);
}

public static void openFolder(File folder) {
    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(folder);
    }
}
```

Be awrae that if you call this with a File that is no directory at least Windows will try to open the file with the default program for the filetype.

But I don't know on which platforms this is supported.