# Creating a GUI for screen recorder

Tags: java, popup, jframe

I was looking at Randel Schofer's screen recorder and I like the GUI. I was trying to design a one on my own without looking at the source code. I know that is the easy way out but I want to figure out the things on my own.
I came across a lot of issues:
[image: problems]

**How do I get a background like that?** I know `GradientPaint` can do that. I have used that to fill rectangles and circles but how can I use it for a `JFrame`?

**How do I add that arrow?** I know how to add an image for a button but those are 24 x 24 and quite large so I don't know what that is

**Is that a JPopupMenu?**

I know how to create them and give them functionality but all of my popup menus have been inside the `JFrame`

**What is that? When I click, it opens the 'Videos' folder Question says it all

**How do I add that timer?** Do I need a thread to maintain the time? If yes, how do I go about with the `run()` method?

*edit:*

```
public class ScreenRecorder extends JFrame{
    protected class background extends JPanel{
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        }
    }
}
```

I still can;t get the background. Please help.

Comment: Indeed, you can acquire that background by overriding `paintComponent` and then using a `GradientPaint`.  The arrow is also most likely an image, but it could also be plain text; either way, it's most likely on a `JLabel`, and the label likely has a `MouseListener` to handle creating the likely `JPopupMenu` off of the clicked point.  As for opening the "Videos" folder, that's a simple `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(..)` of a command like `explorer C:\somedir\somedir\Videos`.

Comment: @Vulcan A tad bit more on the last one please. I know 'Videos' folder has a predefined location in Windows. How do I know what OS is my program running on? Then, depending on OS, the location must be set :)

Comment: You can determine OS through the `System` property `os.name`, acquired via `System.getProperty("os.name")`.  If it contains "Windows", you're running Windows; if it contains "Mac", you're running Mac. Linux, Solaris, FreeBSD, etc. might have special cases however, so I recommend researching/testing them if you need unique cases for them.

Comment: You mean, you want to create a stopwatch? If so, use swing timer: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

Comment: As for the timer, it's likely just formatting the time elapsed, calculated by the difference between `System.nanoTime()` when you start recording, and `System.nanoTime()` of the current time.

Comment: @brano88 this is a screen recorder so every second that `--.--` is updated. `Timer` only has a `start()` and `stop()` which are executed only once, I guess. So how do I update the time?

Comment: A Swing `Timer` is intended for scheduling events (such as capturing the screen every 30 milliseconds).  For determining time elapsed, use the difference between `System.nanoTime()` at two different points in time.  A `Timer` *can* be used to tracking elapsed time, but it's unnecessary to use it like so.

Comment: Look @sdasdadas answer. BUT...be careful with that timer! When you start it, you should also stop it before exiting from your application. So you should make a window listener which will stop it, if close button on your `JFrame` is clicked. Also you can stop it violently by passing `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` as an argument in `setDefaultCloseOperation()` method..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Override the paintComponent of the JPanel inside the JFrame and draw the gradient much in the same way you do for a Shape.
2. You'll have to create that image in Photoshop / GIMP, and then add it to a JLabel or a JButton (depending on interactivity).
3. Yes - it is still inside of the JFrame technically (set on the JLabel/JButton within the JFrame). It's just it draws outside because the JFrame is so small.
4. [java: Open folder on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134096/java-open-folder-on-button-click)
5. The timer can be implemented as such:

   ```
   ActionListener listener = new ActionListener()  
           {  
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  
               {  
                   // Update the display with the time.
               }  
           }; 
   timer = new Timer(speed, listener);
   timer.setInitialDelay(pause);
   timer.start();
   ```

Comment: and how do I add that timer?

Comment: You should probably separate these into different questions next time since you've already deconstructed the GUI correctly. I will edit my answer, though, with the timer.

Comment: OK, so I extended `JFrame` and it says I cannot override `paintComponent()` as I must override some super class method. I know `JFrame` is a `JComponent`

Comment: I'm sorry - I meant override on your JPanel /within/ your JFrame.

Comment: Ok, I added the code to the question. If you can still help

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219762/call-paintcomponent-for-a-jpanel-in-jframe

It's a pretty common question on SO.

Comment: More specifically (gradient): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220853/how-to-make-the-background-gradient-of-a-jpanel